# sbt Project name must be valid Scala identifier error while creating new project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I wanted to create a new project in scala in intellij. I have chosen Lightbend Project Starter and then Akka Quickstart Scala. On finish I got this error:

```
sbt Project name must be valid Scala identifier
```

The name of my project is "akka-demo" but "akkademo" and default "untitled" don't work either. Empty catalog is created. Same with other templates. How can I overcome this?

Env:

1. Intellij idea ultimate 18.3.4
2. sbt 1.2.6

Comment: "akkademo" should work. Perhaps the UI isn't updated correctly? Does it work if you try to create a new project directly and call it "akkademo"?

Comment: It does not work either, I have tried restarting.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your problem locally. Creating such a project from template works fine for me. Could you open a ticket on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL and describe in detail how to reproduce?

Comment: Ok, thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, `akkademo` should indeed work.
It sounds like an IntelliJ problem.

If a project directory was created, you can try to remove the `.idea` directory and reimport the project.

Furthermore, you can download the [Akka Quickstart Scala](https://developer.lightbend.com/start/?group=akka&project=akka-quickstart-scala) project from Lightbend's website, and start the sbt shell in this directory.
Try to run and compile to make sure your environment is set up correctly.
If everything works with the sbt shell but not in IntelliJ, then open:
`IntelliJ` -> `Preferences` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Build Tools` -> `sbt` and check the `Use sbt shell for imports and for builds`.
Then go to the `sbt` tab in IntelliJ and refresh.

Comment: Yes, I did download the project from their site:) but the directory is completely empty.

Comment: I downloaded the project and it is not empty. You should be able to access the files via terminal/file browser. Perhaps you mean that IntelliJ shows this as an empty directory (since importing the sbt project fails?). Try to run sbt via terminal in the project directory and compile it. It should work. Comment here with the result. Then setup the project in IntelliJ - don't forget to mark *use sbt shell for builds*

Comment: I mean the project is empty when creating via intellij. With the one i downloaded from lightbend everything is alright

Comment: did you try to close IntelliJ, delete the `.idea` directory and to check the `Use sbt shell for imports and for builds` when re-importing the project?

Comment: I did try restarting intellij. The directory is empty, there is nothing to delete or import from.

Comment: Don't just restart IntelliJ. Also, you should delete the `.idea` directory from the file system, not from IntelliJ. Go to `File` -> `Close Project`. Do this for all opened projects until you reach the `Welcome to IntelliJ IDEA` screen. You will have a project list on the left of this screen. Hover over the project name and click the x icon. Delete the .idea directory (from the terminal/file browser. not from IntelliJ). Then click on `open` in IntelliJ and select the project's directory. When you create the new project, make sure to select `Use sbt shell for imports and for builds`.

Comment: It's an IntelliJ issue. Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-19192